# Is it possible to use ggplot with the units package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, units-of-measurement

The units library simplifies working with units. Plotting with units works fine with base plot, but not with ggplot, as far as I know. Any suggestions?

```
library(units)

# Take cars data frame: stopping dist (ft) vs speed (mph)
plot(cars)

# units + base plot
Distance = set_units(cars$dist, ft)
Speed = set_units(cars$speed, mph)
plot(x=Speed, y=Distance) #Clean

# units + ggplot
library(ggplot2)
df = cars
df$Disance = set_units(df$dist, ft)
df$Speed = set_units(df$speed, mph)

qplot(x=Speed, y=Distance, data=df)
# Error in Ops.units(x, range[1]) : 
#   both operands of the expression should be "units" objects
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ggforce`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/) that solves this problem.
More specifically, see [`scale_unit`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/scale_unit.html).

```
# install.packages("ggforce")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

df = cars
df$Distance = set_units(df$dist, ft)
df$Speed = set_units(df$speed, mph)

qplot(x=Speed, y=Distance, data=df)
```

[image: Resulting plot]

You obtain the same result like this to avoid to avoid to transform the data.

```
qplot(x=speed, y=dist, data=cars) +
    scale_x_unit(unit = 'mph') +
    scale_y_unit(unit = 'ft')
```

## Notes

- This answer gives me the idea to write a [post](https://www.back2code.me/2020/04/may-the-force-be-with-the-units/) on this topic to play with units and plots.
- There is currently an [issue](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/issues/190) with the latest version of ggplot that drops axis values. It's possible to switch to the development version while waiting for the new version to be released: `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/ggforce")`.