Use ggplot2 and units package to define aesthetic mappings
I would like to create a plot where a variable (say z) defines a colour scheme for some points in a ggplot. For example:
library(ggplot2)
library(units)
#> udunits database from C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/units/share/udunits/udunits2.xml

set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5, 
  y = 1:5, 
  z = runif(5)
)

ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, col = z))


However, as soon as I specify that the variable z is recorded with a given unit of measurement, the same code fails
dat$z <- set_units(dat$z, "m")
ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_point(aes(x, y, col = z))
#> Error in Ops.units(x, range[1]): both operands of the expression should be "units" objects

Created on 2024-05-23 with reprex v2.0.2
Is it possible to fix the previous code?

color = as.numeric(z)?

Yes, sure but, IMO, that kinda defeats the point of using the units package. Maybe this is just currently not implemented, and I can create a feature request at GitHub page of the units package.

Ah, turns out there is an answer already, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61209769/903061

IMO that doesn't answer my question. In fact, it is possible to use unit objects to create (gg)plots. However, that error is raised only when a unit object is used to specify an aesthetic (i.e. col) other than x and y, and this type of problem is not discussed in that link. In fact, AFAICT, nowadays, we don't even need to use ggforce anymore (something which is also discussed here).

And the NEWS file suggests that this has been part of the units package since version 0.8.0, and this resolved issues shows use of units::scale_x_units.

Hmm, yes it does seem they made a strange choice to implement scale_x_units and scale_y_units, but ignore the other scales. I would suggest opening an issue in the units package.

Just for reference, I opened a new issue here.
